# Python cannot get url params

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, tornado, urlparse

I want to get the param of a url that is sent back to the server when the user submits the form. However I get this error `AttributeError: 'HTTPServerRequest' object has no attribute 'get'`

My url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset?key=0OeKkQcSRXiy6yAvtgd9GGv4DhO1t0EYuybjHG5Buzo=`

The url string is created as:

```
keyVal=base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes + uuid.uuid4().bytes)
emailLink = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset?key=%s'%keyVal
```

The `emailLink` is a used as a link.

I tried to retrieving the value of the param `key` in the above url as:

```
class ResetPwdHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):       
    def get(self):
        self.render("reset.html")

    def post(self):
        value = self.request.get('key')
        print value
```

I receive the other form data fine, using `self.get_argument()`, if I try to use it here then it says 'key' is missing argument.

I see examples that use `urlparse` but how could you use this to get the param of the url when the form is submitted.

Comment: Maybe the context is obvious to other users, but can you show the full class definition? The error is that the 'HTTPServerRequest' object has no attribute 'get', but where is `request` set and where is its class defined?

Comment: I've edited question to shoe the whole class

Comment: What framework is this? Where is BaseHandler from?

Comment: This is Tornado framework

Comment: Where is `self`'s `request` assigned? Where is `get` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Tornado or its web framework, but the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest) is quite clear that the request class doesn't define a `get` method. You are perhaps confusing it with Flask or webapp2. It seems like you can either do `self.request.arguments['key']` or `self.get_arguments('key')`.

Comment: Thanks; Yes I had to use `self.get_arguments('key')` as well, I had it incorrectly in `def post` not  `def post`.